# Get previous week between only this current month in Ruby

Tags: ruby, date, datetime

I have got last week's first date and the last date in July month in the following code but I have got 28 June as the first date of the last week. I want to get starting the week at 1 July to 2 July as a week. I won't get back to the previous month.

Every weekday range is Monday to Friday.

```
(Date.today - Date.today.wday - 6).strftime('%d %b') => "28 Jun" 
(Date.today - Date.today.wday - 2).strftime('%d %b') => "02 Jul"
```

Have any suggestions for this? All help is appreciated.

Comment: Is this what you want, `DateTime.now.beginning_of_month` ? I don't understand exactly what you are asking.

Comment: Here, https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveSupport/CoreExtensions/Date/Calculations/beginning_of_month, there are other useful methods, beginning_of_week, etc. Maybe you find something ...

Comment: My weekday range is Monday to Friday.  "at_beginning_of_week" and "at_end_of_week" by respectively we get starting of the week(Monday) and end of the week(Sunday) but this date range should be 1 July to 30 July.  Above my code, we can get the previous week of the current date. We get the "28 Jul" to "2 Jul" week range if we check that in the rails console. we get this cause according to Monday to Friday range. The issues are, I don't want to get 28, 29, 30 June. Thursday(1 July) to  Friday(2 July) can a week of this current month. @razvans

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if there is an one-liner to solve this. But here's my take on solving this mentioned logic

```
def previous_week_in_current_month(selected_date)
  previous_week_date = selected_date - 1.week
  (previous_week_date.month == selected_date.month) ? previous_week_date : selected_date
end
```

The `previous_week_in_current_month` returns the previous week of the current_date in the current month and if the provided date is from the first week, it returns the current date. Maybe if you want you can make it to return nil.